# Парсер веб-страницы

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

После парсинга с помощью кода:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
all=[]
site= ""
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = Request(site,headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
table = soup.find("div",{"class": "sell_orders_box"})
#rows = table.find_all("td")
for rows in table.find_all("td"):
    list=rows.text
    print(list)
```

Получаю список значений

```
0.00112424
0.00005767
54.17461418
```

если ввожу     `print(type(list))` то выводит кучу

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

Как мне объединить эти строки в списки по 3 строки?

Answer (score 0):

```
...
table = soup.find("div", {"class": "sell_orders_box"})
td_list = [rows.text for rows in table.find_all("td")]
print(td_list)
```